# Parameter Overloading to avoid developer's mistakes and to follow a custome rule

Tags: c#

```
public enum HeaderDisplayType
        {
            singleColumn,
            table,
            doubleColumn
        };
```

This is my enumeration

```
public Worksheet crWsheet<T>(string masterHeading, List<T> list, ExcelCreator.HeaderDisplayType headerType = HeaderDisplayType.doubleColumn)
{
        method body
}


public Worksheet crWsheet<T>(string masterHeading, List<T> list, ExcelCreator.HeaderDisplayType headerType = HeaderDisplayType.doubleColumn, string RowName="Row1")
{
        method body
}
```

developer access these by "

```
objectName.crWsheet("heading", intList, ExcelCreator.HeaderDisplayType.singleColumn)
```

if a developer enters a comma after the enumeration part he can see the other string parameter "RowName".
Please tell me how to restrict developers accessing the second method when they are not using the enumeration " singleColumn ". In other words allow developers to access the second method when they only use the enumeration "single Column"

In this way developers will be able to follow a condition without facing any trouble. It depends on the business scenario of the model.

This should be done without changing the method name and only defining parameters based on the above explained condition

thank you

Answer (score 2):

Your question isn't clear but, I think your after this structure:

```
public Worksheet crWsheet<T>(string masterHeading, List<T> list)
{
       ExcelCreator.HeaderDisplayType headerType = HeaderDisplayType.doubleColumn
}


public Worksheet crWsheet<T>(string masterHeading, List<T> list, string RowName)
{
        ExcelCreator.HeaderDisplayType headerType = HeaderDisplayType.singleColumn;
}
```

So providing `RowName` now implicitly says your using `singleColumn` and not specifying this implies `doubleColumn`

Answer (score 2):

If the second method should be used only with HeaderDisplayType.doubleColumn parameter value, than you should remove headerType parameter from it:

```
public Worksheet crWsheet<T>(string masterHeading, List<T> list, ExcelCreator.HeaderDisplayType headerType = HeaderDisplayType.doubleColumn)
{
    // method body
}


public Worksheet crWsheet<T>(string masterHeading, List<T> list, string RowName="Row1")
{
    var headerType = HeaderDisplayType.doubleColumn;
    // method body
}
```

For additional header display types you have to use classes instead of enums:

```
public class NamedRowHeaderType : RowHeaderType 
{

}

public class RowHeaderType
{

}

public class HeaderDisplayType
{
    public static NamedRowHeaderType doubleColumn = new NamedRowHeaderType();
    public static NamedRowHeaderType table = new NamedRowHeaderType();
    public static RowHeaderType singleColumn = new RowHeaderType();
}

class Sample
{
    public Worksheet crWsheet<T>(string masterHeading, List<T> list, ExcelCreator.RowHeaderType headerType = null)
    {
        headerType = headerType ?? ExcelCreator.HeaderDisplayType.doubleColumn;
        //method body
        return null;
    }


    public Worksheet crWsheet<T>(string masterHeading, List<T> list, ExcelCreator.NamedRowHeaderType headerType = null, string RowName = "Row1")
    {
        headerType = headerType ?? ExcelCreator.HeaderDisplayType.doubleColumn;
        //method body
        return null;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Sample s;
        s.crWsheet<string>("", null, ExcelCreator.HeaderDisplayType.singleColumn);
        s.crWsheet<string>("", null, ExcelCreator.HeaderDisplayType.doubleColumn, "Row1");
        s.crWsheet<string>("", null, ExcelCreator.HeaderDisplayType.singleColumn, "Row1"); // compile error
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no way to add a compile-time restriction for enum value. You should throw an exception is case of singleColumn passed to the second method. Or replace Enum with two classes with static fields/properties.

Comment: added a sample for classes instead of enums